# Password_hash not hashing

Tags: php

I am using php 7.1.6. I am trying to use password_hash but it does not seem to be working. Here is my code:

```
$post = $this->input->post();
$maxid = $this->db->query('SELECT MAX(App_Users.ID) AS MAXID FROM App_Users')->row()->MAXID;
$maxid = $maxid + 1;
$hash = password_hash($post['Password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO APP_USERS (ID, NAME, PASSWORD) 
VALUES(".$maxid.", '".$post['Name']."', '". $hash ."')");
```

The password is being stored without hashing. $post['Password'] = '1234' and it is being stored in the DB as '1234'.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `$post` is coming from where?

Comment: Please, var_dump $post

Comment: `$hash` is a string, not an integer - Edit: once `password_hash()` kicks in.

Comment: Please read http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php carefully... :)

Comment: Not possible. You're not showing the entire code.

Comment: try do like echo password_hash("1234", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";

Comment: Your acceptance record is questionable.

Comment: @Harisudhan.A that `."\n"` - do you realize what that does/stores? There's a user contributed note about that in the manual, you should read it.

Comment: Either you left the question or are waiting for a magic solution. The latter won't happen and I can assure you of that, up until that we know exactly what we're dealing with here. I myself have given enough time and attention to now leave the question, seeing no response on your part in comments, and in question to be updated; good luck.

Comment: I modified the code to make sure that $hash is a string in the insert query. I also added some more line of code to clarify. This code is a webservice and the $post is coming from a thrid party application using POST method. I am using postman to test. It is being read correctly but it stores the password as it is being received (without hashing)

Answer (score -1):

```
 //this is normal way to generate has password//
$hash = password_hash("input value", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO APP_USERS (ID, NAME, PASSWORD) 
VALUES(".$maxid.", '".$post['Name']."', '". $hash ."')");

//In this way we can provide cost and salt to generate hash value//

$options = [
'cost' => 11,
'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM),
 ];
$hash = password_hash("input value", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
```

input value that what you have sening through  $post['which value that you want to hashing'] .

Hope it will help to you

Comment: It is recommended not to provide a salt but to let `password_hash` create the salt. Also in PHP 7.x the salt option has been removed. See [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), "If omitted, a random salt will be generated by password_hash() for each password hashed. This is the intended mode of operation."